# Does the HERE maps iOS SDK provide default icons like the Android SDK does?

Tags: ios, here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

My team is using HERE android(java) and iOS(obj-c) SDKs to add map/turn-by-turn navigation to our existing react native app, and would want to keep the visuals as consistent as possible across both platforms.

The android SDK provides a default marker from HERE to render map markers (see screenshot below), but does the iOS SDK provide a way to use the same default marker? All the iOS map marker documentation/examples we have seen use custom icons/images for map markers.

[image: (android marker)]

Also, does HERE SDK provide navigation maneuver icons, like the ones shown in the top left of their example screenshot for turn-by-turn navigation (see screenshot below); and how would you go about accessing them. Would like to know before committing to finding/creating our own icons.

[image: map navigation screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There are two open source projects from HERE that contain free-to-use maneuver icons and more:

- iOS: https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-ios/tree/master/MSDKUI/Assets
- Android: https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-android/tree/master/MSDKUIKit/MSDKUILib/src/main/res

Both projects target the 3.x HERE SDK. If you are looking for the new 4.x HERE SDK, you may want to look into this open source project from HERE:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-ref-app-flutter

It also contains many open source assets, plus it shows a full production-ready app including all the source code to build a turn-by-turn experience:

[image]